# QGIS 2.8 Labels are lost when setting map rotation with crs on the fly

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.8

I was working with QGIS 2.8.1. When I set the map rotation in canvas the canvas rotated as wished but all the labels were **lost**. I found out if I disable CRS OTF(on the fly) all the labels will be displayed correctly.

So the question is how to render labels correctly with map rotaion and CRS OTF enabled in QGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known bug in 2.8 - see http://hub.qgis.org/issues/12025

Comment: Thanks! I have read the bug report , and now waiting some fix.